# Issue in reading XLS by POI on Android

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

I am facing an issue in reading an XLS file with POI in an Android project.  To read the file I have done this:

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = getInstrumentation().getContext().getAssets().open("abc.xlsx");
} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

This resolved the read issue but now I am facing another issue with this code:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

This gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
at com.evernote.test.Xls_Reader.<init>(Xls_Reader.java:36)
at com.evernote.test.Main.readTestCaseXls(Main.java:87)
at com.evernote.test.Main.testCreateAccount(Main.java:62)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)
```

I have included all necessary POI libraries and with those libraries it works fine in the Java project.  The issue is in the Android project.

I have added this jar in project->properties->Javabuild path->Add external jar. I have included following jar poi-scratchpad-3.9-20121203, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203, poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203, poi-ooxml-3.9, poi-excelant-3.9-20121203, poi-examples-3.9-20121203, poi-3.9-20121203, In order and export i have not checked the poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203 jar if i checked this then it give error {Dx trouble writing output: Too many methods: 66024; max is 65536. By package: 13 java.lang 1 java.lang.reflect}.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that there are a number of problems that you might run into when using Apache POI on Android. You can avoid the error about too many methods with a feature called "multiDex" in newer versions of Android.

There are currently two projects which try to solve most of the problems for you:

1. https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx
2. https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/ (mainted by me)

The first one is currently based on POI 3.12, whereas the second can be re-compiled with newer versions of POI more easily.

Answer (score 0):

if you get this exception even when you are sure that you have included all the jars then create a libs folder in the project root directory and copy all jars in libs folder. the add these jars in java build path (select all jars and right click add jars.)